# How to correct minutes value with moment.js?

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

I need to some correct Date minute value like the following:

```
var d = new Date();
d.setMinutes(d.getMinutes() < 30 ? 0 : 30);
```

So if minutes less than "30" that it should be "0" and if greater than "30" that "30";

Is it possible by using [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should be able to do the same thing using `.minute(value)`:

```
var m = moment(new Date());
m.minute(m.minute() < 30 ? 0 : 30);
```

[Here is the section](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/minute/) of the docs.

Comment: Is there util moment.js method for this task?

Comment: I don't know of one. It is a pretty specific requirement.  I wouldn't think a library would support this out of the box.